# Normal/rankit scores from non-normal data with ties for regression in [R]

Tags: r

I would like to see whether pathogen levels influenced certain bumblebee colony development parameters such as the number of queen pupae produced.

Due to non-normality of the data I would like to do a rankit transformation of the data as suggested by [Bishara & Hittner (2012)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22563845).

> To define this transformation, let x_r be the ascending rank of x, such
>   that x_r = 1 for the lowest value of x. The RIN transformation function
>   used here is
>
> f(x)= Φ^(-1) ((x_r-0.5)/n)
>
> where Φ^(-1) is the inverse normal cumulative distribution function and
>   n is the sample size (Bliss, 1967).

I could not figure out how to do the rankit transformation in R. I tried this:

```
my.df$queen.pupae_rankit = qnorm((rank(my.df$queen.pupae)-0.5)/length(my.df$queen.pupae))
```

However, the ties seem to prevent a normal distribution of the rankit scores:

```
qqnorm(my.df$queen.pupae_rankit)
```

[image]

Therefore, I would like to know

1. How can I get rankit scores from data with ties in R?
2. Is the qnorm function actually the correct function to get the inverse cumulative distribution function?
3. [Bishara & Hittner (2012)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22563845) used the rankit scores in Pearson correlations rather than regressions. I know in a regression only
   the independent variable has to be normally distributed. Should I
   anyway, as [Bishara & Hittner (2012)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22563845) did transform also the
   dependent variable?

PS. I also looked into the 
rntransform {GenABEL} , rankInverseNormalDataFrame {FRESA.CAD} and qNormScore {SuppDists}, but I could not figure out how to use them to get the rankit scores I want. The data looks like this:

```
structure(list(queen.pupae = c(0L, 0L, 131L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 
0L, 141L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 45L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 84L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 116L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 92L, 1L, 45L, 
120L, 137L, 40L, 100L, 119L, 74L, 8L, 41L, 19L, 1L, 52L, 32L, 
123L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 162L, 68L, 10L, 0L, 20L, 229L, 2L, 87L, 219L, 
143L, 82L, 1L), worker.adults = c(146L, 185L, 181L, 145L, 244L, 
185L, 152L, 114L, 254L, 337L, 210L, 290L, 162L, 186L, 84L, 166L, 
295L, 107L, 229L, 203L, 125L, 183L, 246L, 217L, 22L, 106L, 150L, 
112L, 45L, 116L, 120L, 152L, 66L, 78L, 65L, 160L, 149L, 247L, 
60L, 193L, 255L, 184L, 300L, 41L, 96L, 101L, 37L, 45L, 291L, 
353L, 158L, 243L, 146L, 128L, 40L, 390L, 129L, 59L, 77L, 663L, 
295L, 498L, 254L, 449L), pathogen1.dna = c(0, 318111.127271693, 
0, 68623.2739754326, 1574.45287019555, 34424.6122347574, 2400.58041860919, 
43515.3059302234, 4832293.58571446, 8799.05541479988, 0, 28825.2443389828, 
0, 1523.13350414953, 8865474.42623986, 0, 0, 521807.198120121, 
5174641.18054382, 0, 15904014.4954482, 43560.4440044516, 0, 25389.0067977301, 
388996.478514811, 95206.2277317915, 11828659.0129974, 807202.672709897, 
5359061.63083682, 0, 21041.1231283436, 31817666.6056002, 4545923.10675542, 
10685.8600591283, 16115.7029438609, 0, 67887826.6688623, 16943.6858267549, 
1492919.02988919, 49436.4613189687, 711743.102574896, 0, 23651052.7433696, 
76175.2980832307, 21563.8738983475, 76520.1382493025, 164861.507683675, 
2203260.57078847, 24348427.1595032, 134749.527642678, 276476.323303274, 
10329030.0039368, 93822.2696353729, 12872122.4242484, 31680707.4838652, 
6701547.09356281, 2369578.88255313, 1413650.78332731, 522467.993244771, 
989515.406542198, 3837021.29623798, 1020067.61286839, 37534060.9859563, 
43371163.4363934)), .Names = c("queen.pupae", "worker.adults", 
"pathogen1.dna"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -64L
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use a different method for dealing with ties in the ranks. For example: 
   `rank(my.df$queen.pupae, ties.method = "random")`. Have a look at `?rank` for more options.
2. Yes, I believe `qnorm` is the right function here!
3. I don't think so, but I'm not sure. You could try ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

1. The code in your question already does produce the rankit scores.  If you were to randomly break ties, as with `rank(...,ties.method="random")`, that would introduce random error into the transformation result.  Unfortunately, any univariate transformation method that doesn't introduce random error will preserve the ties, and lead to similarly non-linear QQ plots.
2. Yes
3. Only the dependent variable should be transformed, not the independent ones.  Transforming the dependent variable will often help normalize the residuals, and that's the particular normality assumption that regression relies on.